# How to assign .xsd for ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, gml

GMLAS link:
http://www.gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html

I want to convert my gml file to shapefiles. But our gml files was created by custom gml schema. We have their application schema, xsd. But i don't know how to put this schema path on command prompt or python ide. 
I downloaded fwtools, ogr2ogr main python code but i don't know to use.
Do you know how?

Comment: Don't use FWTools, it is out of date (with an ancient GDAL 1.6 or 1.7) and no longer supported. Use OSGeo4W.  The GMLAS driver is only available in GDAL >= 2.2

Comment: Okay. so as i know osgeo4w can be downloaded and is used to install gdal ogr libraries. But it's relevant because i used ogr2ogr.py main file and couldn't success and i still don't know what is this syntax and where do i have to put .xsd schema path to convert gml to shp. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used GMLAS, but the documentation shows you would use something like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -oo XSD=input.xsd output.shp input.gml
```

The [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) doc shows that `-oo` can be used to specify format specific open options. The [GMLAS driver page](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html) you link to shows the available open options for the GMLAS format.

You can do this in python using the [GDAL python API](http://www.gdal.org/python/) with:

```
in_ds = gdal.OpenEx('input.gml', open_options=['XSD=input.xsd' ])
out_ds = gdal.VectorTranslate('output.shp', in_ds, format = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

But you could also just use

```
subprocess.check_output(['ogr2ogr', '-f', "ESRI Shapefile", '-oo', 'XSD=input.xsd', 'output.shp', 'input.gml'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried GDAL python api, appears epsg code error but it is not important because osgeo shows same error too. however, end of the traceback, it shows : "ERROR 1: hSrcDS == NULL" . I couldn't find out how to resolve. Additionally i tried to run as using subprocess: i assigned osgeo.bat path, .xsd file and gml files but it is not successful again : 'subprocess.check_output(osgeoshell, ['-f', "ESRI Shapefile" '-oo', 'XSD=%s' % muipxsd, shpoutputs, muipgml]) '

Answer (score 1):

@user2865 Thanks

For me it works to transform cityGml to shapefiles

```
xsd = "XSD=http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/landuse/1.0/landUse.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/cityfurniture/1.0/cityFurniture.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/texturedsurface/1.0/texturedSurface.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/transportation/1.0/transportation.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/building/1.0/building.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/waterbody/1.0/waterBody.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/relief/1.0/relief.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/vegetation/1.0/vegetation.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/cityobjectgroup/1.0/cityObjectGroup.xsd,http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/generics/1.0/generics.xsd"
in_ds = gdal.OpenEx("GMLAS:" + inputFile, open_options=[xsd, "REMOVE_UNUSED_LAYERS=YES"])
out_ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(outputFolder, in_ds, format = 'ESRI Shapefile', layerCreationOptions = ["SCHEMA=citymodel"])
```