# How to use WFS access point to create a GeoJSON of data displayed on QGIS canvas when ogr2ogr does not find schema?

Tags: wfs, ogr2ogr, gml, inspire, xsd

The German state of [Schleswig-Holstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleswig-Holstein) has a [geoportal](https://advmis.geodatenzentrum.de/trefferanzeige;jsessionid=F19A503EFE413DAE8DC59B246C27817B?docuuid=defbc2f3-52f0-4b0e-a196-908d678086b3&plugid=/ingrid-group:iplug-csw-dsc&docid=X4Cl9XYBWW0O27vjZYKZ), where they provide a link to their WFS service:

https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

Making it possible to access the state's cadastral data. I would like to **create GeoJSON files of parcels of a small area programmatically** (i.e. without using the export capabilities of QGIS or anything else involving clicks). I connect to the service with QGIS and observe the requests sent with the Network Logger:

[image]

One of the requests:

```
6632 GET https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=499366.66208086209371686,6042488.79555566236376762,500991.50434459594544023,6044824.24658435396850109,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)
```

Relying [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446603/191643) and the question [How does QGIS extract features from the XML response of an INSPIRE WFS server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446578/how-does-qgis-extract-features-from-the-xml-response-of-an-inspire-wfs-server), I try:

```
URL="https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=499366.66208086209371686,6042488.79555566236376762,500991.50434459594544023,6044824.24658435396850109,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
curl $URL -o inspire.xml
```

So far so good, the xml file seems to contain parcel polygons:

[image]

Continue with:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON inspirecp.json GMLAS:inspire.xml cadastralparcel
```

Output:

```
ERROR 3: Cannot resolve http://lxtrspa011.dpaorinp.de/aaa-suite/schema/inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `GMLAS:inspire.xml' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
# and many more drivers
```

The link to the `xsd` file [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) is looking for (http://lxtrspa011.dpaorinp.de/aaa-suite/schema/inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd) indeed seems dead (failed to access it via browser too). If I follow the link at the end of the request sent by QGIS (http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0), there is a `CadastralParcels.xsd` file available:

https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd

I download this file (`curl "https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd" -o CadastralParcels.xsd`) and try to feed it to `ogr2ogr` using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280588/how-to-assign-xsd-for-ogr2ogr):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON parcelsTest.geojson inspire.xml CadastralParcel -oo XSD=CadastralParcels.xsd
```

Output:

```
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
```

(I also tried `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM CadastralParcel" parcelsTest.geojson inspire.xml -oo XSD=CadastralParcels.xsd`, which failed too.)

The produced `parcelsTest.geojson` only contains reference points, not parcel polygons. `head -c2000 parcelsTest.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "CadastralParcel",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "areaValue": 967.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "548", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100548______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499537.314000000013039, 6042680.542999999597669 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "areaValue": 2024.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "571", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100571______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499593.968999999982771, 6042767.157999999821186 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "areaValue": 1243.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "551", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100551______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499546.956, 6042727.576999999582767 ] } },
{ "type": "F%
```

QGIS is able to connect to the WFS endpoint and display parcel boundary information (along with metadata, if I use the `Identify Features`) tool. I would like to access the same information via `ogr2ogr` (or any other scriptable tool).

**How can I use [the WFS link](https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getCapabilities) to download parcel data into GeoJSON files?**

---

A further observation. While [in the referenced answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446603/191643), `ogrinfo GMLAS:inspire.xml` works, in this case, `ogrinfo GMLAS:inspire.xml` returns:

```
ERROR 3: Cannot resolve http://lxtrspa011.dpaorinp.de/aaa-suite/schema/inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `GMLAS:inspire.xml' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
  -> FITS
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDS4
  -> VICAR
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
# and many more drivers
```

---

Trying to follow the advice in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448651/191643), I attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=499366.66208086209371686,6042488.79555566236376762,500991.50434459594544023,6044824.24658435396850109,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
curl $URL -o inspire.xml

right_schema_url="https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=describeFeatureType&typename=cp:CadastralParcel"
curl $right_schema_url -o schema.xml

ogrinfo -so -al -oo XSD=schema.xml inspire.xml # <- works nicely

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON parcelsTest.geojson inspire.xml CadastralParcel -oo XSD=schema.xml # <- still fails
```

which still fails, with `head -c2000 parcelsTest.geojson` giving

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "CadastralParcel",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "areaValue": 967.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100548______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "548", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100548______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499537.314000000013039, 6042680.542999999597669 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "areaValue": 2024.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100571______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "571", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100571______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499593.968999999982771, 6042767.157999999821186 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "areaValue": 1243.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2011-05-31T17:01:14Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_01159600100551______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.sh.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": "551", "nationalCadastralReference": "01159600100551______", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 499546.956, 6042727.576999999582767 ] } },
{ "type": "F
```

Comment: The DescribeFeatureType schema is invalid according to oXygen XML validator.  You should edit the schema.xml file and replace the `http://lxtrspa011.dpaorinp.de/aaa-suite/schema/ogc/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd` schema location with `https://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the required schema for the layer by using:

```
https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=describeFeatureType&typename=cp:CadastralParcel
```

You can then specify the open option `XSD=filename` to your OGR command to override the schema location.

```
ogrinfo -so -al -oo XSD=schema.xml inspire.xml
```

It is probably also worth notifying the owners of the portal that their output is broken.

Comment: Thanks! Attempting to make this work...

Comment: The `ogrinfo`command indeed works, thanks! I haven't been able to make the `ogr2ogr` bit work though (details: see appended question).